# How to hide output to logfile for password variable?

Tags: install4j

We created a custom action and injects the password given by the password field of a configurable-form-component. Now in the logfile the password is printed as cleartext. How can we hide the password the same way it is at the input-form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call

```
context.registerHiddenVariable("variableName");
```

In install4j 6, this can be configured in the GUI as well (Installer->Installer Variables->Configure Predefined->"Sensitive information" check box).

---

**Update:**

To prevent the logging of a property in a custom action, implement `com.install4j.api.beans.PropertyLoggingInterceptor` and implement it like this:

```
@Override
public Object getLogValueForProperty(String propertyName, Object propertyValue) {
    if (propertyName.equals("secretProperty")) {
        return "***";
    } else {
        return propertyValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I have to specify the hidden variable at my customized action? I tried the `init`-method but the property value is alway shown at the log file.

Comment: OK, you want to hide the property not a variable. See my edit.